# NodeJS Net server crashes upon nmap scan

Tags: javascript, node.js, nmap

I have programmed a server based on the Net module of NodeJS. It works perfectly fine, if I try to connect to it using a Net socket. However, if I try to scan it with nmap, it can't write to the socket, giving an `EPIPE` error.

```
    Error: write EPIPE
    at afterWriteDispatched (node:internal/stream_base_commons:160:15)
    at writeGeneric (node:internal/stream_base_commons:151:3)
    at Socket._writeGeneric (node:net:775:11)
    at Socket._write (node:net:787:8)
    at writeOrBuffer (node:internal/streams/writable:400:12)
    at _write (node:internal/streams/writable:341:10)
    at Socket.Writable.write (node:internal/streams/writable:345:10)
    at Server.<anonymous> (/server.js:6:10)
    at Server.emit (node:events:379:20)
    at TCP.onconnection (node:net:1555:8)
Emitted 'error' event on Socket instance at:
    at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:188:8)
    at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:153:3)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:81:21) {
  errno: -32,
  code: 'EPIPE',
  syscall: 'write'
}
```

I have simplified the server code to this:

```
const net = require('net');
const server = net.createServer(socket => {
  socket.write('Test');
});
server.listen(30);
```

The nmap output just sais `30/tcp open  tcpwrapped`.
I'm sure it has something to do with how nmap connects to the server. But I just can't work out how.

Comment: The reason this is an issue is, that anyone could take down the server.

Comment: What connects to the server? `EPIPE` in the [list of errors](https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors) says "...indicative that the remote side of the stream being written to has been closed."

Comment: Btw (probably unrelated), your server never closes the connection.

Comment: I'm scanning locally with nmap. So localhost connects to the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you're getting this error is that nmap closes the connection immediately. By the time your callback starts executing, Node.js has already got the RST packet and it knows the connection is closed, so it disallows writes to it by throwing an error right away - a socket is a state machine that makes sure of this.

As a rule, you should be ready to handle connection state errors *at all times* - potentially, any write call can fail. This is different than losing packets because, in this scenario, they never reach the network.